# Direct Proof: If two integer numbers are divisible by a number a, then so is their difference.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUm1B.png)

I tried writing the direct proof for the proposition above. I was wondering it it's correct. Is there a better way to write this? Am I counting the variables in my domain correctly? All help is appreciated

Comment: Never post unsearchable images of text and equations.  Instead typeset (using *MathJax*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would be the direct proof for the following statement: If two integer numbers are divisible by a number a, then so is their difference.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3861266/what-would-be-the-direct-proof-for-the-following-statement-if-two-integer-numbe)

Comment: Yes, actually I posted that after someone pointed out that using pictures might not be very useful if I'm looking for help. Thank you:)