# What would be the direct proof for the following statement: If two integer numbers are divisible by a number a, then so is their difference.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

f two integer numbers are divisible by a number a, then so is their difference.
∀x,y ∈Z a|x ∧ a|x → a|x−y

Proof.
a|x ∧ a|x

x=a∗b   for some a,b ∈ Z

y=a∗c   for some a,c ∈ Z

x−y=ab−ac  for some a, b, c ∈ Z

x−y=a(b−c) for some a, b, c ∈ Z

Let d = b−c

x−y=ad  for some d ∈ Z

a|x−y

I tried writing the direct proof for the proposition. Can someone let me know if this is correct? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

your proof is completely true but the point is what you said in the beginning because it's a famous and very important theorem in number theory:
a|b and a|c then a|mb+nc,a|mb-nc

a,b,c,m,n are integers